# SQL Server: Two table join show all rows where there's no data per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, report, outer-join

I'm trying to create a report query that shows for a given date range, all the names, with the dates, and if there's data.  I'm really close but I'm at a loss on how to get these final zero values in the data.  So here's what I want:

```
 Name   ID     Mth Day Count
 Auburn  7261   10  14  0
 Auburn  7261   10  15  0
 Auburn  7261   10  16  0
 Auburn  7261   10  17  0
 Auburn  7261   10  18  0
 Concord 7262   10  14  2
 Concord 7262   10  15  0
 Concord 7262   10  15  0
 Concord 7262   10  17  1
 Katey   7263   10  14  0
 Katey   7263   10  15  0
 Katey   7263   10  16  0
 Katey   7263   10  17  0
 Katey   7263   10  18  0
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
 Name   ID     Mth Day Count
 Auburn  7261   10  14  0
 Auburn  7261   10  15  0
 Auburn  7261   10  16  0
 Auburn  7261   10  17  0
 Auburn  7261   10  18  0
 Concord 7262   10  14  2
 Concord 7262   10  17  1
 Katey   7263   10  14  0
 Katey   7263   10  15  0
 Katey   7263   10  16  0
 Katey   7263   10  17  0
 Katey   7263   10  18  0
```

Here's my query:

```
 SELECT PUE.Name as [Name], pue.EventID,
 MONTH(dates.Date) AS Month, DAY(dates.Date) AS Day,
 puc.idcount AS PicturesTaken
 from (
 select name, eventid from Events where 
 TourID = 444 and EventID > 7256 and EventID < 7323
 ) PUE
 outer apply (
SELECT
    Date = DateAdd( Day, n1.number * 10 + n0.number, '2014-10-14' )
FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) as n0
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) as n1
WHERE   DateAdd( Day, n1.number * 10 + n0.number, '2014-10-14' ) BETWEEN '2014-10-14' AND '2014-10-18'
 ) dates
 left outer join (
 select eventid, convert(date,picturetakendate) as picdate, count(consumerdataid) as idcount from ConsumerData
 where EventID > 7256 and EventID < 7323 
 group by eventid, convert(date,picturetakendate)
 ) puc
 on pue.EventID = puc.EventID 
 where puc.picdate = dates.Date or puc.idcount is NULL
 order by pue.eventid, MONTH(dates.Date), DAY(dates.Date)
```

I get why the zeros are not showing up for the names, here's the outer joined table results:

```
 7262   2014-10-14  2
 7262   2014-10-17  1
 7265   2014-10-14  2
 7266   2014-10-14  2
```

So it makes sense that in the where clause that its not null or matching a date.  But if I take out the where clause I get a row for every count for every date i.e.:

```
 Concord    7262    10  14  2
 Concord    7262    10  14  1
 Concord    7262    10  15  1
 Concord    7262    10  15  2
 Concord    7262    10  16  2
 Concord    7262    10  16  1
 Concord    7262    10  17  1
 Concord    7262    10  17  2
 Concord    7262    10  18  2
 Concord    7262    10  18  1
```

I'm so close, I know there just just something simple I'm missing but each attempt I make to fix it actually makes the results worse, so I'm here for help.  I figure I just need to wither fix the query in the outer join to somehow show every date , which if I could reference the dates apply would be easier or change the where.  But I've been unable to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ISNULL condition in the SELECT clause

```
 SELECT PUE.Name as [Name], pue.EventID,
 MONTH(dates.Date) AS Month, DAY(dates.Date) AS Day,
 ISNULL(puc.idcount,0) AS PicturesTaken
```

convert where clause to ON

```
on pue.EventID = puc.EventID 
AND puc.picdate = dates.Date
```

instead of

```
where puc.picdate = dates.Date or puc.idcount is NULL
```